# Making a Continue button work using SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-button

I'm quite a beginner as far as java and android studio is concerned. So, I'm building a simple riddle game. Each activity consists of a question and a Text Field to place your answer - right answers get you to the next one etc.

The main activity has two buttons: a New Game one (which works fine) and a Continue one - the one that troubles me. Obviously, what I want is that, when pressed, it takes you to the last question you reached. I'm aware that SharedPreferences must be used in order to get this done, my problem is that I fail to think of a piece of code that works (every tutorial I've seen and read was about keeping names - high scores etc).

Here's my code: it may need some polishing, but I'm still learning.

**Main Activity java**

```
public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mStartInterrogationButton;
    private VideoView mLogoprwto;
    private Button mContinueButton; //This one is the one I'm asking about

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);


        mLogoprwto = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.logoprwto);
        mLogoprwto.setVideoPath("android.resource://my.path/"+R.raw.teloslogo);
        mLogoprwto.start();

        mLogoprwto.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                mLogoprwto.start();
            }
        });

        mStartInterrogationButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.StartInterrogationButton);
        mStartInterrogationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startGame();

            }
        });

    }

private void startGame () {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Question01.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**Question One activity java (next ones are the same)**

```
    public class FirstQuestion extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mSayAnswer;
    private EditText mAnswerbox;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_question);

        mAnswerbox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Answerbox);
        mSayAnswer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.SayAnswer);

        mSayAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String answer = mAnswerbox.getText().toString().trim();
                if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("nothing")){
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), QuestionTwo.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }else if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("black")) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), QuestionTwo.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }else {

                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMenu.class));
        finish();
    }
};
```

Thanks in advance, I've been looking for a solution for this for quite a few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is to save whether or not the user has answered each question correctly in the SharedPreferences. Then in your MainActivity, send them to the right question depending on how many they've answered correctly. For example:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("FILENAME", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putBoolean("Question01", true);
editor.apply();
```

Here, FILENAME is the name of the file to write your SharedPreferences to and 'Question01' would be the tag you would save the boolean under for the first question.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("FILENAME", MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean question01Answered = prefs.getBoolean("Question01", false);
```

Then you'd call the above to check if Question01 has been answered or not. In your continue button's onClick() method you could do a series of checks to see how far the user has reached and send them to the appropriate Question Activity.

```
if (!(question01Answered)) {
    // question01Answered is false and has not been answered. Send them to the first question.
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Question01.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
} else if (!(question02Ansered)) {
    // question02Answered is false and has not been answered. Send them to the second question.
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Question02.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
} else if (!(question03Answered)) {
   // and so on...
}
```

**EDIT:** The first section of code can be called anytime you want to save data for a certain question. For example if your user answers the 5th question right then inside the Question05's activity class, you would run the first piece of code right after you confirm that the user answered correctly. Something like:

```
public class Question05 extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...

    private void checkIfQuestion05IsCorrect() {
        if (correct) {
            // They answered right, move to the next question.
            // But before we do that, let's save the fact that they answered right.

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("FILENAME", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putBoolean("Question05", true);
            editor.apply();
        } else {
            // they got it wrong
        }
    }

}
```

As for the second piece of code, call it in the MainActivity right before doing all the checks in your continue button's onClick() method, or whenever else you want to know which questions they've answered and which ones they haven't.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("FILENAME", MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean question01Answered = prefs.getBoolean("Question01", false);
boolean question02Answered = prefs.getBoolean("Question02", false);
boolean question03Answered = prefs.getBoolean("Question03", false);
// and so on ...

if (!(question01Answered)) {
    // question01Answered is false and has not been answered. Send them to the first question.
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Question01.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
} else if (!(question02Ansered)) {
    // question02Answered is false and has not been answered. Send them to the second question.
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Question02.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
} else if (!(question03Answered)) {
   // and so on...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time :) Although I have to apologise for I haven't fully comprehended where on my code should I add your pieces... I got the third (onClick) part, but I cannot understand where the first two are meant to be put. By "file" (where I write my SharedPreferences) you mean I should create a new java tab, and put them there? I'm really sorry about this, but I'm just getting the grasp of it :)

Comment: No problem. For your second question, SharedPreferences saves data to an XML file in your app's storage. So when you provide a filename in the call to getSharedPreferences(), it opens that file for reading and writing (it also creates the file if it does not exist). You don't actually have to worry about this parameter too much aside from making sure you're opening the same file you saved the data to.

As for your first question, I've added an update to answer it.

Comment: Now everything starts making sense - thanks to you I started understanding the logic behind your code. One last thing though... While everything seems fine, I get a red underline in my (this,Question01.class); parts (intents of main activity), and a message appears that says "Cannot resolve constructor intent". I found the solution by replacing "this" with "MainActivity.this", but now 90% of the times I press continue, it just takes me to Question01. Once it just got me to the last question answered - another one just did nothing. I know it's too much, really can't thank you enough for this.

Comment: Could you show me where you are creating the Intent?

Comment: Just reviewed my code - it was a typo that made the button go nuts. I wholeheartedly thank you once again for your patience and help :) Good luck with your career pal, already checked your apps!